# gcc assembler preprocessor not compatible with standard headers

Tags: gcc, assembly, c-preprocessor

The man page for gcc states

```
   file.s
       Assembler code.

   file.S
   file.sx
       Assembler code that must be preprocessed.
```

And many standard include files have

```
#ifndef __ASSEMBLY__ 
...
#endif
```

wrappers to allow inclusion from assembly files.  I could have sworn I've written programs before with gcc and it defined this when assembling, but now I'm running into problems.

Here's some test code:

test.S

```
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <asm/signal.h>
    .intel_syntax noprefix

    .text
    .global foo // int foo(int pid)
foo:
    mov esi,SIGUSR1
    mov eax,SYS_kill
    syscall
    ret
```

When I run `gcc -c test.S`, it complains about all kinds of stuff in the asm/signal.h because it doesn't see `__ASSEMBLY__` defined.

For now my work around is:

```
#ifndef __ASSEMBLY__
#define __ASSEMBLY__
#endif
```

But this just seems wrong to have to add this to all my files.

Is this a bug in GCC?
Or am I doing something wrong here?

NOTE:
I see in a test that gcc does define `__ASSEMBLER__` but most of the header files test for `__ASSEMBLY__` (I do see a couple that test for `__ASSEMBLER__`).  Was the appropriate ifdef changed at some point?

I am using Ubuntu 14.04, and gcc reports version: gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2

Comment: Run `gcc -dM -E - < /dev/null` or even `echo > empty.S; gcc -dM -E empty.S` to understand which preprocessor symbols are predefined by your compiler.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I already know the symbol is not defined. I ran your second test, and it confirmed this.  This seems like a bug if gcc is defining `__ASSEMBLER__` but the standard headers are checking for `__ASSEMBLY__`.

Comment: You could define it yourself on the `gcc` comand line, with `-Wa,--defsym,__ASSEMBLY__=1`

Answer (score 16):

`__ASSEMBLY__` is a convention that the Linux kernel project made up themselves before they knew about the existence of the gcc predefined macro `__ASSEMBLER__`.

The linux kernel passes down `__ASSEMBLY__` explicitly in [linux/Makefile](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.16/source/Makefile#L513):

```
KBUILD_AFLAGS   := -D__ASSEMBLY__
```

There were patches posted on LKML to migrate to `__ASSEMBLER__` in 2005 but they were not merged: [Re: [RFC][MEGAPATCH] Change **ASSEMBLY** to **ASSEMBLER** (defined by GCC from 2.95 to current CVS)](https://lkml.org/lkml/2005/9/10/111)