# How to preprocess and compile an assembly file(.s) using gcc?

Tags: gcc, assembly, c-preprocessor

I have a .s file which needs to be preprocessed before compiling it using GCC. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest way is to rename the file to be `.S` instead of `.s` -- the `.s` extension mean assembler *without* preprocessing while `.S` means assembly *with* preprocessing.

Comment: Or use `gcc -x assembler-with-cpp ...`

Comment: This also creates the define `__ASSEMBLER__` which can be used for conditional headers to allow sharing of constants between 'C', C++ and assembler.  Ergo, the include directive works.  Unless you intend to write your entire application in assembler, this might be helpful.  [Many bothans died to bring you this information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28924355/gcc-assembler-preprocessor-not-compatible-with-standard-headers).

Comment: @artlessnoise Do you mean that the `.S` extension causes it to be defined? Or that using `-x assembler-with-cpp` does? Or that either/both of them would cause `__ASSEMBLER__` to be defined?

Comment: @AJM  They are equivalent.  Ie, `.S` will automatically use `-x asembler-with-cpp` (meaning 'C' pre-processor).  So, gcc has some built-in defines and `__ASSEMBER__` is one of them, when pre-processing assembler.  This allows you to conditionalize shared header files between C/C++ and assembler.