# GCC macro which can discriminate C and assembly mode

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, linux-kernel

I'm building 3rd-party linux kernel module driver.

When I trying to build signed kernel module, gcc complains with following warnings:

```
include/linux/compiler.h: Assembler messages:
include/linux/compiler.h:61: Error: no such instruction: `struct ftrace_branch_data{'
include/linux/compiler.h:62: Error: no such instruction: `const char *func'
include/linux/compiler.h:63: Error: no such instruction: `const char *file'
...
```

In `scripts/Makefile.modpost`, make tries to build signed kernel module with `gcc -x assemble-with-cpp .. [many options] .. -include [some_c_header_file] ..`. That is, it tries to compile assembler source file but it has C header file in it's `c_flags` and I suspect this is the problem. When I manually set up build comment without `-include [some_c_header_file]`, then build is successful.

It's not easy to remove that C header file only from `c_flags` for modpost phase only, since it is used for normal compilation.

So I wonder if there are any MACRO that is valid both for gcc assembly and C, and can be used to make following code block run only for non-assembly mode.

Any helps will be appreciated deeply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Use `#ifndef __ASSEMBLER__`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html#Standard-Predefined-Macros):

> `__ASSEMBLER__`
>
> This macro is defined with value 1 when preprocessing assembly language.

Though Linux kernel build seems to utilize a macro named [`__ASSEMBLY__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28924355/gcc-assembler-preprocessor-not-compatible-with-standard-headers) too.